# Show that $ \sum q^{-\deg \ p(x)} $ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

> Show that $\sum q^{-\deg  \ p(x)}$ diverges, where the sum is over all monic irreducibles $p(x)$ in $K\left[x\right]$, where $k$ is finite field with $q$ elements.

First show that  $\sum q^{-\deg  \ f(x)}$ diverges and that  $\sum q^{-2\deg  \ p(x)}$ converges, where both sums over all monic polynomials $f(x)$ in $K[x]$. There are exactly $q^{n}$ monic polynomials of degree $n$ in $K\left[x\right]$.

Consider $\sum_{\deg \ f(x )\leq n} q^{-\deg  \ f(x)}$, this sum is equal to $\sum_{m=1}^{n} q^{m}q^{-m}= n+1$, thus $\sum q^{-\deg  \ f(x)}$ diverges. $ \ $ Similarly $\sum_{\deg \ f(x )\leq n} q^{-2\deg  \ f(x)}$ is equal to $\sum_{m=1}^{n} q^{m}q^{-2m} \leq (1-\dfrac{1}{q})^{-1}$, thus $\sum q^{-2\deg  \ f(x)}$ converges.

As would the rest of the proof?

Comment: Your proof doesn't sum over irreducibles. You need to show that the number of monic irreducibles of degree $n$ is $\sim q^n/n$. There are many resources (in particular, a few questions on MSE) on how to calculate the number of monic irreducibles of given degree using generating functions and Mobius inversion.

Answer (score 0):

The number of irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $K$ is 
$$
\sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d) \,q^d \;,
$$
so you have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{q^{-n}}{n} \left( \sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d) \,q^d \right) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\left(1-\sum_{p|n} q^{-n(p-1)/p} + \dots\right)$$
and all terms but the first converges as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and the divergence is proved.
The second question is similar, but in this case you don't get the divergence of the harmonic series.